# document.getElementById("id") returns the whole object correctly but not value although there is one

Tags: javascript

The whole app looks more or less like this:

```js
  let request = null

  function sendApiRequest() {
    request = document.getElementById("input")
    console.log(request)
    console.log(request.value)
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="input" class="box inp"><input type="text"></div>
  <div id="textbox" class="box tb"><textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea></div>
  <div id="send" class="box b1"><button type="button" name="button" onclick="sendApiRequest()">Send request</button></div>
  <div id="reset" class="box b2"><button type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Clicking the button with `sendApiRequest()` method returns the `<div>` element, but no value (`undefined`) from the input, although there IS some text typed into the input box.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Output of `console.log(request)` ?

Comment: a `div` does not have a `value`

Comment: `input` is the id of the wrapper `div`, it was probably meant for the `input`. You could change `document.getElementById("input")` to `document.querySelector("#input input")`

Comment: how can u get value of div? 
  <div  class="box inp"><input type="text"  id="input" ></div>
request = document.getElementById("input")

Comment: `request.firstElementChild.value`

Comment: or `request = document.querySelector("#input>input")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is of input and is a child of input id. So you need to reference `children[0]`

```js
  let request = null

  function sendApiRequest() {
    request = document.getElementById("input")
    console.log(request)
    console.log(request.children[0].value)
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="input" class="box inp"><input type="text"></div>
  <div id="textbox" class="box tb"><textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea></div>
  <div id="send" class="box b1"><button type="button" name="button" onclick="sendApiRequest()">Send request</button></div>
  <div id="reset" class="box b2"><button type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Other possible solutions:

- `request.firstElementChild.value` an alternate way of referencing the input div child element
- `request = document.querySelector("#input>input")` change request to reference input inside of div
- `request = document.querySelector("#input input")` ditto
- give the input an id and query that specifically (`document.getElementById("myInputId")`)

Comment: personally ... I'd use `request = document.querySelector("#input>input")` :p

Comment: there are like a billion ways to solve this, this was the first that came to mind

Comment: Yeah, I agree - though, 999,999,995 of those ways are probably odd variations on the 5 ways you could actually do it :p